# How to convert j2ee project to salesforce application

Tags: integration, appexchange, website-integration

It s been some time that I have implemented a web project using Java J2EE and it is now in production on the internet but now I want to have a new SF application. So my questions are

1 - How I can put my web project on the AppExchange in order to enable salesforce users to install my web project into their SF ?

2 - Do I need to change any implementation for payment modules ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Salesforce own Heroku that can host JEE code. But Salesforce itself has its own configuration mechanisms and proprietary languages so you will have to re-write your application in those.